# Discord get guild member list with php curl

Tags: php, laravel, curl, discord

I am using [socialite](http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/discord/) to get the access token:

```
return Socialite::driver('discord')
->scopes(['email', 'identify', 'connections', 'guilds', 'rpc.api', 
'guilds.join'])
->redirect();
```

The call back url is providing me the details, since there is no friend list API call I am trying to get user list of guilds with members detail, for this I use curl:

```
$authToken ="MYTOKEN";
$url="https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/guilds";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Authorization: Bearer '.$authToken),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The API call works fine and gives me a list of guilds with their id's. For example one of the id's was 431731422857003020, but when I tried to make another API call with curl to [get list of members](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#list-guild-members)

```
$url="https://discordapp.com/api/v6/guilds/431731422857003020/members";
```

It gave me this error:
`{"code": 0, "message": "401: Unauthorized"}`

I am not sure if it is because I should use a different method to get the member list or if I should add a different scope, I searched everywhere, but did not see any proper documentation about [discord scopes](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes)

Comment: I don't believe you have permission to retrieve the members' basic information, the documentation wasn't fully clear regarding that endpoint.

Comment: I am getting guilds and guilds.join permission inside scope, I can not find any other scope name for getting guild member list

Answer (score 1):

You should set header like that: `Authorization: Bot {BOT_TOKEN}`